# Spring REST validation response details

Tags: java, rest, validation, spring-mvc

Trying to write simple test application using Spring REST and AngularJS using server-side Spring validation.

In REST controller wrote such code:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/people")
    public class PeopleResource {

    //...

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new PeopleValidator());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    @ResponseBody
    public ResultDTO add(@Valid @RequestBody PeopleDTO peopleDTO) {
    // ...
    // some code to save to database
    // ...
        return new ResultDTO(id.toString());
   }
}
```

And the validator:

```
public class PeopleValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return PeopleDTO.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors e) {

        PeopleDTO p = (PeopleDTO) target;

        if (p.getName().toLowerCase().equals("disallowedname")) {
            e.rejectValue("name", "Disallowed name");
        }
    }
}
```

And code in AngularJS service and controller:

```
        //...
        function add(data) {
            return $resource('rs/people', {}, {'add': {method: 'POST'}}).add({}, data);
        }
        //...

        //...
        people.add(newPeople).$promise.then(
            function(){
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            },
            function(res){
                // do something to say there are problems
            }
        );
        //...
```

Ok, validator works fine. I get into PeopleValitator, get an error with message "Disallowed name".

In the client-side code, response(res value in js code) looks like HTML containing message "HTTP ERROR 400" and nothing about specific error.

Experienced people, for example [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/), write it would be response like JSON containing specific error information, but I can't get such behavior, maybe doing something wrong.

Also here could used BindingResult as a paramether in REST method, it works, but I think it's not best idea.

Please, help, what should I do in this sample to get validation error information on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

400 bad request means that your request doesn't match the PeopleDTO object. So make sure your request contains all the mandatory attributes in the PeopleDTO.

Comment: Ok, thank you. 
But how can I get on client side something like "400. Bad request just because of 'disallowed name' "?